# Python - How to express integers in functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering how would you express integers in a function. Lets say you have to express m as an integer that goes from 1 to 12. m would be a month. I am still early in regards to learning python, so I am currently only working with if, else, and if statements.

for example

```
def day(d,m):
    if m = [1,2,3,4...12]
```

Comment: Can you show some code that you have tried?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking, please explain more and best show some code.

Comment: @Yozuru But how do you want to use it? Please provide more context.

Comment: Apologies. 

For example would m = [1,2,3,4,5...12]

Comment: I would like to use it to list 1-12 in regards to month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly what you are looking for

```
if m in range(1,13):

if 1 <= m < 13:
```

Comment: made a mistake : edited

Comment: The second argument to `range` is exclusive.  Meaning, it should be `range(1,13)` for the numbers `1` through `12`.

Comment: Although this is almost certainly not the best way to do what OP is trying to do, this is EXACTLY how to do what he ASKED to do. +1

Comment: Thank you floppy! if 1 <= m <= 13 is the range I was looking for. I'm still new to python and I am still learning everyday. Thanks to everyone for helping me and apologies for the confusion I have caused.

Comment: should be `<= 12`, not `13`.

Comment: @Yozuru `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]`? Those aren't months....